# Using Hibernate Search (Lucene), I Need to Be Able to Search a Code With or Without Dashes

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

This is really the same as it would be for a social security #.

If I have a code with this format:

```
WHO-S-09-0003
```

I want to be able to do:

```
query = qb.keyword().onFields("key").matching("WHOS090003").createQuery();
```

I tried using a WhitespaceAnalyzer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *StandardAnalyzer* or *WhitespaceAnalyzer* both have the same problem. They will index 'WHO-S-09-0003' as is which means that when you do a search it will only work if you have hyphens in the search term. 
One solution to your problem would be to implement your own *TokenFilter* which detects the format of your codes and removes the hyphens during indexing. You can use *AnayzerDef* to build a chain of toekn filters and an overall custom analyzer. Of course you will have to use the same analyzer when searching, but the Hibernate Search query DSL will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can implement your own method like this one:

```
private String specialCharacters(String keyword) {
    String [] specialChars = {"-","!","?"};

    for(int i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++ ) 
        if(keyword.indexOf(specialChars[i]) > -1)
            keyword = keyword.replace(specialChars[i], "\\"+specialChars[i]);

    return keyword;
}
```

as you know lucene has special chars, so if you want escape special chars than you should insert before that char double backslashes...